# Substracting pointers: how variable j is getting this value?

Tags: c, pointers

So I have a program in C. its running but I don't understand how the output is generated ??

**Here is the program :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int c;
void main() {
    int a=10,b=20,j;
    c=30;
    int *p[3];
    p[0]=&a;
    p[1]=&b;
    p[2]=&c;
    j=p[0]-p[2];
    printf("\nValue of p[0] = %u\nValue of p[2] = %u\nValue of j = %d\n\n",p[0],p[2],j);
}
```

**and Here is the output :**

```
Value of p[0] = 3213675396
Value of p[2] = 134520860
Value of j = -303953190
```

**Can anyone tell me how j got this value i.e. -303953190** ?? It is supposed to be **3079154536**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing 3213675396 - 134520860. If you want to get the value use *p[0]. If your intention is to substract the address(which doesnt make sense but still) the expected answer should be 3079154536. But since the number if too large to hold hence you get the answer -303953190. Consider char for simplicity on number line

-128 -127 -126 -125 ... 0 1 2 ... 125 126 127

Now if you try to store 128 it out of range so it will give value -128. If try to assign value 130 you will get -126. So when the right hand side limit is exceeded you can see the counting starts from the left hand side. This is just for explanation purpose only the real reason for this behavior is owed due the fact that it is stored as two's compliment. More info can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Thanks ishant for the explanation. I knew the value is so big to get stored in j that's why it is negative. But can you explain in detail how it got that value ?

Answer (score 1):

`p` is array of pointers to int - so its storing pointers to int and not ints. Hence, `p[0]` and `p[2]` are pointers - subtracting them will give you an integer which may overflow that you are trying to store in an `int` where the problem lies. Also addresses are to printed using `%p` not `%d`.

Dereference the value and you will get what you are looking for, like this:

```
j=p[0][0]-p[2][0];
```

or like this:

```
j=*(p[0])-*(p[2]);
```

Comment: From what do you conclude the OPs want the difference of what `p[0]` and `[2]` point to?

Comment: @alk - The OP's question is `Can anyone tell me how j got this value i.e. -303953190 ??` - i never stated h/she wants the difference. I just stated why he/she got weird results. I think the OP as well did not want the difference of 2 pointers and landed up doing something unintended.

Comment: Even more: "*subtracting them will give a pointer*" this is not true, it resolves to an integer. Also pointer differences are to be printed using the `t` length modifier.

Comment: Actually I didn't wanted to subtract the values on the two addresses I.e. j=*p[0]-*p[3]. I intentionally subtracted the two addresses and assigned it to an int to see how int handles it. I know int j isn't big enough to contain value after subtraction so it overflows. That's why its going to be negative.  But I really wanted to know how it getting that value. int is 4 bit here.

Answer (score 1):

You should compute the difference of the pointed objects rather than of the pointers:

```
 j=(*(p[0]))-(*(p[2]));
```

Comment: From what do you conclude the OPs want the difference of what `p[0]` and `[2]` point to?

Answer (score 1):

Substracting two pointers results in a signed integer.

From the *C Standard chapter 6.56*:

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
>
> [...]
>
> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is **ptrdiff_t** defined in the **< stddef.h>** header.

And assigning the pointer difference to an `int` overflows the `int`.

To get around this overflow instead of

```
int j;
```

use

```
ptrdiff_t j;
```

and then print the value using `%td`.

From the *C Standard chapter 7.17*:

> **7.17 Common definitions** < stddef.h>
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The types are
>   **ptrdiff_t**
>   which is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers;

---

Also (unrelated)

```
void main()
```

is wrong. It shall be

```
int main(void)
```

---

So the correct code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* for ptrdiff_t */

int c;

int main(void) 
{
  int a=10, b=20;
  ptrdiff_t j;
  int * p[3];

  c=30;

  p[0]=&a;
  p[1]=&b;
  p[2]=&c;

  j=p[0]-p[2];

  printf("\nValue of p[0] = %p\nValue of p[2] = %p\nValue of j = %td\n\n",
    (void *) p[0],
    (void *) p[2],
    j);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing it as an integer instead of an unsigned. Use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int c;
void main() {
    int a=10,b=20;
    unsigned j;
    c=30;
    int *p[3];
    p[0]=&a;
    p[1]=&b;
    p[2]=&c;
    j=(unsigned)p[0]-(unsigned)p[2];
    printf("\nValue of p[0] = %u\nValue of p[2] = %u\nValue of j = %u\n\n",(unsigned)p[0],(unsigned)p[2],j);
}
```

Comment: [I accidently deleted my comment, so here it comes again]: `j` **is** declared to be a **signed** integer. And pointers are printed using the conversion specifier `%p` along with being casted to `void *`.

Comment: I know. That's why he's getting an unexpected result. He is casting an `int*` to `int` in the assignments.